# Wordpress sidebar not visible

Tags: php, wordpress

In my `footer.php` I've added `<?php get_sidebar('lj_sidebar'); ?>` In my `functions.php` I've enabled widgets: `add_theme_support('widgets');` and made a action hook `add_action('widgets_init', 'lj_widgets');`

Then in my `widgets.php` I make the widget like this:

```
<?php

function lj_widgets() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('My First Theme Footer','lnj'),
        'id'            => 'lj_sidebar',
        'description'   => __('Footer for my first theme','lnj'),
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
}
```

In my `sidebar.php` I check if the sidebar is enabled:

```
<?php

if(is_active_sidebar('lj_sidebar')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('lj_sidebar');
}
```

The widget is visible in my admin panel. But when I put for example a textfield in it. It's not showing up?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there is no issue in this code. Its working fine for me. we need some more details.

Comment: you can call widget in sidebar by using this code if(is_active_sidebar('lj_sidebar')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('lj_sidebar');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `get_sidebar( 'lj_sidebar' );`, WordPress is looking for the file `sidebar-lj_sidebar.php` and not `sidebar.php`.

You're calling your sidebar correctly with `dynamic_sidebar( 'lj_sidebar' );` which says, "Display the widget area with the id `lj_sidebar`" but it's not displaying on the front-end because you're telling WordPresss to display the contents of `sidebar-lj_sidebar.php` which presumably doesn't exist.

Either:

1. Rename your `sidebar.php` to `sidebar-lj_sidebar.php`, or
2. Change your sidebar call from `get_sidebar( 'lj_sidebar' );` to `get_sidebar();`.